# Tumblr theme posts - hidden date and tags not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, tumblr, tumblr-themes

***EDITED MAY, 26TH:***

I'm using the coding you'll see below as an answer from @AchrafJEDAY (I'll also include it here as well). The coding as broke somehow, and when I click on the date or tag buttons to show the date or tag for ANY post, it freaks out; you see it for just a moment before the whole page refreshes with "/?" at the end of the URL and the date and tags are both hidden again. I'm not sure why this is, but I'd SUPER appreciate ANY help anyone has! Thank you!!

CODING:

CSS

```
.postdatebutton{
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                width:50px;
                height:15px;
                border:1px #83174C solid;
                background-color:rgba(255, 230, 240, 0.8);
                font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
                letter-spacing:2px;
                text-align:center;
                padding-top:5px;
                color:black;
                font-size:14px;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .postdatebutton button{
                font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .postdate{
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                display:none;
            }
            /*TAGS*/  
            .tags {
                width:415px;
                text-transform:uppercase;
                line-height:120%;
                font-size:15px;
                text-align:center;
                padding:2px;
                text-decoration:underline;
                -moz-transition-duration:0.5s;
                -webkit-transition-duration:0.5s;
                -o-transition-duration:0.5s;
            }
            .tags a {
                color:#BB0B20;
                letter-spacing:1px;
                padding:1px;
            }
            .posttagbutton{
                float:left;
                position:relative;
                top:0px;
                left:0px;
                width:50px;
                height:15px;
                border:1px #83174C solid;
                background-color:rgba(255, 230, 240, 0.8);
                font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
                letter-spacing:2px;
                text-align:center;
                padding-top:5px;
                color:black;
                font-size:14px;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .posttagbutton button{
                font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
                text-decoration:underline;
            }
            .posttag {
                width: 100%;
                text-align: center;
                display:none;
            }

            #stuff table{
                position:relative;
                width:100%;
                text-align:center;
            }
```

HTML

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
        <!---LIKE----> 
<td><div class="postlike">{LikeButton}</div> </td>
        <!---REBLOG----> 
<td><div id="postreblog"><a href="{ReblogURL}">Reblog</a></div> </td>
        <!---NOTES----> 
<td><div class="postnote">{block:NoteCount} <a href="{Permalink}">Notes</a>{/block:NoteCount}</div> </td>
        <!---VIA----> 
<td><div class="postfrom">{block:RebloggedFrom}<a href="{ReblogParentURL}">From</a>{/block:RebloggedFrom}</div> </td>
        <!---SOURCE----> 
<td><div class="postsource"> {block:ContentSource}<a href="{SourceURL}">Orig-Poster</a>{/block:ContentSource}</div> </td>
        <!---DATE BUTTON----> 
<td><div class="postdatebutton"><button onclick="myFunction6(this)">Date</button></div></td>
        <!---TAGS BUTTON----> 
<td><div class="posttagbutton"><button onclick="myFunction7(this)">Tags</button></div></td></tr></tbody></table>
            <!---HIDDEN DATE----> 
<div class="postdate" style="display:none;"><p>{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}"> {MonthNumberWithZero}-{DayOfMonthWithZero} {24Hour}:{Minutes}</a>{/block:Date}</p></div>
            <!---HIDDEN TAGS----> 
<div class="posttag" style="display:none;"><div class="tags"><p>{block:Tags}<a href="{TagURL}">#&nbsp;{Tag}</a>{/block:Tags}</p></div></div>
```

JS

```
<!---SCRIPT FOR DATE AND TAGS----> 
<script>
function myFunction6 ( event ) {

    var node = event.parentNode;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    var x = node.getElementsByClassName("postdate");
    if (x[0].style.display === 'block') {
        x[0].style["display"] = "none";
    }
    else {
        x[0].style["display"] = "block";
    }

}
</script>
<script>

function myFunction7( event ) {

    var node = event.parentNode;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    var x = node.getElementsByClassName("posttag");
    if (x[0].style.display === 'block') {
        x[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        x[0].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: You need to reference the date and tag sections that are in the same container as the button that has been clicked.

Comment: You should not use `id` to identify post date and post tag. id must not repetead in a page, and javascript can't select more than one elements identified by the same id. Use `class` instead.

Comment: @AchrafJEDAY I don't quite understand what you mean..... I've included all the coding I believe...

Comment: you should not use the same id more than one time in a page use classes instead.

Comment: @vlk Thanks! I'll try that!!
But then how do make the line in the JS 'var x = document.getElementById('posttag');' work, since it's looking for the id..... Sorry, new to JS! :P

Comment: just change the HTML to use class attribute instead of id.

Comment: But what about the JS? It's going off of an id not a class - and idk how to do the JS with classes instead of ids :/

Comment: function myFunction1 ( e ) {

    var x = e.target.parents().eq(5).getElementsByClassName("postdate");

   }

Comment: Can you create a snippet so I can test?

Comment: Thanks @AchrafJEDAY but its not working - just tested it on the theme. And I tried making a thing on jsfiddle but because it uses Tumblr functions, aka "{block:Date}<a href="{Permalink}">{MonthNumberWithZero}-{DayOfMonthWithZero} {24Hour}:{Minutes}</a>{/block:Date}" and stuff like that it didn't work, like at all :S You can take a look, though, if you want https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=Ou4SDaQawa

Comment: okay let me see.

Comment: @Ally B Done See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction1 ( event ) {

    var node = event.parentNode;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    var x = node.getElementsByClassName("postdate");
    if (x[0].style.display === 'block') {
        x[0].style["display"] = "none";
    }
    else {
        x[0].style["display"] = "block";
    }

}

function myFunction2( event ) {

    var node = event.parentNode;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        node = node.parentNode;
    }

    var x = node.getElementsByClassName("posttag");
    if (x[0].style.display === 'block') {
        x[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        x[0].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="stuff"><div class="picsize"><div class="textpost"><h3>  Testing Text Post - Title  </h3><p><span><a href="http://allystestblog1818.tumblr.com/post/159609010143">allystestblog1818</a></span>:</p><blockquote><h2>Headline</h2><h2><b>Headline Bold</b></h2><h2><i>Headline Italic</i></h2><p><b>Bold text,</b> <i>Italic text,</i> <span><a href="http://allystestblog1818.tumblr.com/">Link text</a></span></p><ol><li>Numbered&nbsp;<br></li><li>List<br></li></ol><ul><li>Bullet<br></li><li>List<br></li></ul><blockquote><p>Indented text</p></blockquote><p>Regular text</p><p>Line break<br></p><hr><p>Picture</p><figure class="tmblr-full"><img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/1250d273b9e9b4860d73aa893361ec20/tumblr_inline_oogr5xEk1J1txz9li_540.jpg" class=""></figure><p class=""><span><a href="http://allystestblog1818.tumblr.com/post/159609010143/testing-text-post-title" class="tmblr-truncated-link read_more">Keep reading</a></span></p></blockquote></div></div><div class="picsize"></div><p></p><table><tbody><tr><td><div class="postlike"><div class="like_button" data-post-id="160506016653" data-blog-name="wisdomsprydethemetestblog" id="like_button_160506016653"><iframe id="like_iframe_160506016653" src="https://assets.tumblr.com/assets/html/like_iframe.html?_v=5716f9145cbbcc5e21aa13229de5d4ed#name=wisdomsprydethemetestblog&amp;post_id=160506016653&amp;color=black&amp;rk=4ktb4Bma&amp;root_id=159609010143" scrolling="no" width="20" height="20" frameborder="0" class="like_toggle" allowtransparency="true" name="like_iframe_160506016653"></iframe></div></div> </td><td><div id="postreblog"><a href="https://www.tumblr.com/reblog/160506016653/4ktb4Bma">Reblog</a></div> </td><td><div class="postnote"> <a href="https://wisdomsprydethemetestblog.tumblr.com/post/160506016653/testing-text-post-title">Notes</a></div> </td><td><div class="postfrom"><a href="https://pokemonthemetestblog.tumblr.com/post/159612507917/testing-text-post-title">From</a></div> </td><td><div class="postsource"> <a href="http://allystestblog1818.tumblr.com/post/159609010143/testing-text-post-title">Orig-Poster</a></div> </td><td><div class="postdatebutton"><button onclick="myFunction1(this)">Date</button></div></td><td><div class="posttagbutton"><button onclick="myFunction2(this)">Tags</button></div></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="postdate" style="display:none;"><p><a href="https://wisdomsprydethemetestblog.tumblr.com/post/160506016653/testing-text-post-title">05-10 1:52</a></p></div><div class="posttag" style="display:none;"><div class="tags"><p><a href="https://wisdomsprydethemetestblog.tumblr.com/tagged/Test-text-post">#&nbsp;Test text post</a><a href="https://wisdomsprydethemetestblog.tumblr.com/tagged/tags-tags-tags">#&nbsp;tags tags tags</a></p></div></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But it's still not working ...:S I put it on the theme just like you have, except using CSS instead of doing <div class="postdate" style="display:none;">. When I click on the date button nothing is showing up
https://wisdomsprydethemetestblog.tumblr.com/

Comment: Roll back to the previous state and clear the cache.

Comment: Remove the console.log(x) and use x[0] instead of x.

Comment: Okay, testing again now!

Comment: Not working still.....
Also it starting conflicting with other JS I have for other divs (the FAQ, Navi, blogroll and such you'll see the buttons for on the left on the purple line), so I had to change it from myFunction1(event) to myFunction6(event). Still nothing is happening when I press it...

Comment: Just copy my js snippet and change the html as I did (use classes instead of ids).

Comment: You are not doing as I did.

Comment: It's working!!! :D :D YAY!!
You were right I must have forgotten to copy something you did! It work AMAZING now! Thank you, thank you, thank you SOOO much!!!

Comment: Somthing's broken and idk what, why, or how.......
I havent changed anything, and to even make sure, I copied and pasted your code again @AchrafJEDAY, but still it's being stupid.

When I click on the date button to show the date, it refreshes the page with the /? at the end, same with the tags (although sometimes it DOESNT do this for the tags and it works normally - for the date it does this every time on every post)

Comment: I don't have time now sorry maybe later.

Comment: No worries! Whenever you have the time! Your help will be greatly appreciated! :D